# openstack-install fails with "bootstrap instance started but did not change to Deployed"

Tags: maas, openstack

I am trying to follow the recipe in https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud#instructions and get the following error during step 6, running openstack-install:

`Problem during bootstrap:
{
    'err': 'Bootstrapping environment "maas"
        Starting new instance for initial state server
        Launching instance\n - /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/[node_id]/
        ERROR failed to bootstrap environment:
            bootstrap instance started but did not change to Deployed state:
            instance "/MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/[node_id]/" failed to deploy',
    'output': '',
    'status': 1
}`

I have 8 machines commissioned and in Ready state in MAAS. I have set up the default gateway with NAT so machines on the internal network can access the public internet.

Here is the complete .cloud-install/commands.log:

```
[INFO: 11-17 09:57:39, openstack-install:227] Starting OpenStack Installer v0.99.28
[INFO: 11-17 09:57:39, openstack-install:228] Start command: ['/usr/bin/openstack-install']
[INFO: 11-17 09:57:39, openstack-install:239] Creating juju directories: /home/bakksjo/.cloud-install/juju
[INFO: 11-17 09:57:41, openstack-install:295] Running Liberty release
[INFO: 11-17 09:57:51, installbase.py:132] Performing an Autopilot install
[INFO: 11-17 09:57:51, utils.py:780] pollinate: sudo su - -c 'pollinate -q -r --curl-opts "-k --user-agent uoi/310c8ee0-d558-45fd-b706-ecb708c082dd/IL"'
[DEBUG: 11-17 09:58:11, landscape.py:75] Existing MAAS defined, doing a LDS installation with existing MAAS.
[DEBUG: 11-17 09:58:17, utils.py:627] ssh keys exist for this user, they will be used instead.
[DEBUG: 11-17 09:58:17, multi.py:139] Bootstrapping Juju: JUJU_HOME=/home/bakksjo/.cloud-install/juju juju  bootstrap  --to honorable-advertisement
[DEBUG: 11-17 10:38:21, multi.py:145] Problem during bootstrap: '{'err': 'Bootstrapping environment "maas"\nStarting new instance for initial state server\nLaunching instance\n - /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-4ae361e2-a032-11e6-bf8c-f80f4182edbc/\nERROR failed to bootstrap environment: bootstrap instance started but did not change to Deployed state: instance "/MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-4ae361e2-a032-11e6-bf8c-f80f4182edbc/" failed to deploy\n', 'output': '', 'status': 1}'
[ERROR: 11-17 10:38:21, gui.py:269] A fatal error has occurred: Problem with juju bootstrap.

[ERROR: 11-17 10:38:21, gui.py:270] Problem with juju bootstrap.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 54, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/controllers/install/multi.py", line 146, in do_install
    raise Exception("Problem with juju bootstrap.")
Exception: Problem with juju bootstrap.
[DEBUG: 11-17 10:38:21, error.py:35] showing error view for: Problem with juju bootstrap.
[ERROR: 11-17 11:24:12, ev.py:130] Exception in ev.run():
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ev.py", line 128, in run
    self.loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 278, in run
    self._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 376, in _run
    self.event_loop.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 1326, in run
    self._loop.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 276, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1172, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/asyncio/events.py", line 120, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 393, in <lambda>
    event_loop, callback, self.get_available_raw_input())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 493, in parse_input
    callback(processed, processed_codes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 403, in _update
    self.process_input(keys)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 503, in process_input
    k = self._topmost_widget.keypress(self.screen_size, k)
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/gui.py", line 136, in keypress
    return super().keypress(size, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1128, in keypress
    return self.body.keypress( (maxcol, remaining), key )
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/decoration.py", line 836, in keypress
    return self._original_widget.keypress((maxcol,), key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1587, in keypress
    key = self.focus.keypress(tsize, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/decoration.py", line 621, in keypress
    return self._original_widget.keypress(maxvals, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/container.py", line 1587, in keypress
    key = self.focus.keypress(tsize, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/wimp.py", line 535, in keypress
    self._emit('click')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/widget.py", line 463, in _emit
    signals.emit_signal(self, name, self, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/signals.py", line 264, in emit
    result |= self._call_callback(callback, user_arg, user_args, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urwid/signals.py", line 294, in _call_callback
    return bool(callback(*args_to_pass))
  File "/usr/share/openstack/cloudinstall/ui/views/error.py", line 66, in cancel
    raise SystemExit("Install exited because of error.")
SystemExit: Install exited because of error.
[DEBUG: 11-17 11:24:12, utils.py:59] Juju Version: 1.25.6-trusty-amd64
[INFO: 11-17 11:24:12, utils.py:61] Cleanup, saving latest config object.
```

Here is an excerpt from /var/log/maas/maas.log:

```
Nov 17 09:58:20 rt1 maas.node: [INFO] honorable-advertisement: Status transition from READY to ALLOCATED
Nov 17 09:58:20 rt1 maas.node: [INFO] honorable-advertisement: allocated to user bakksjo
Nov 17 09:58:21 rt1 maas.interface: [INFO] Allocated automatic static IP address 10.1.2.1 for eth0 on honorable-advertisement.
Nov 17 09:58:21 rt1 maas.node: [INFO] honorable-advertisement: Status transition from ALLOCATED to DEPLOYING
Nov 17 09:58:21 rt1 maas.dns: [INFO] Generating new DNS zone file for maas
Nov 17 09:58:21 rt1 maas.dns: [INFO] Generating new DNS zone file for 1.10.in-addr.arpa
Nov 17 09:58:21 rt1 maas.power: [INFO] Changing power state (on) of node: honorable-advertisement (node-4ae361e2-a032-11e6-bf8c-f80f4182edbc)
Nov 17 09:58:24 rt1 maas.power: [INFO] Changed power state (on) of node: honorable-advertisement (node-4ae361e2-a032-11e6-bf8c-f80f4182edbc)
Nov 17 09:58:57 rt1 maas.lease_upload_service: [INFO] Uploading 20 DHCP leases to region controller.
Nov 17 10:38:21 rt1 maas.node: [INFO] honorable-advertisement: Status transition from DEPLOYING to FAILED_DEPLOYMENT
Nov 17 10:38:21 rt1 maas.node: [ERROR] honorable-advertisement: Marking node failed: Node operation 'Deploying' timed out after 0:40:00.
Nov 17 10:38:41 rt1 maas.node_query: [INFO] honorable-advertisement: Power is on.
```

The bootstrap instance indeed is started and I can SSH into it. However, I'm not sure where I should look to identify the problem. The contents of /var/log/cloud-init.log can be found at http://pastebin.com/xrsCR0WG, and for /var/log/cloud-init-output.log see the pastebin kj1UCJid (not allowed to post two links here). The latter contains some error-looking lines such as

```
Attempt 5 to download tools from https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/agent/1.25.6/juju-1.25.6-trusty-amd64.tgz...
curl: (7) Failed to connect to streams.canonical.com port 443: Connection timed out
```

However, the following works from a terminal:

```
ubuntu@honorable-advertisement:~$ wget https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/agent/1.25.6/juju-1.25.6-trusty-amd64.tgz
--2016-11-17 11:19:52--  https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/agent/1.25.6/juju-1.25.6-trusty-amd64.tgz
Resolving streams.canonical.com (streams.canonical.com)... 91.189.88.141, 2001:67c:1360:8001:1::5
Connecting to streams.canonical.com (streams.canonical.com)|91.189.88.141|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 18647709 (18M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘juju-1.25.6-trusty-amd64.tgz’

100%[==================================================================================================================================================================>] 18,647,709  6.99MB/s   in 2.5s   

2016-11-17 11:19:55 (6.99 MB/s) - ‘juju-1.25.6-trusty-amd64.tgz’ saved [18647709/18647709]
```

So it doesn't look like a NAT setup issue. But, for the sake of completeness, here's the iptables setup on the MAAS node:

```
rt1:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -S
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.0/24 ! -d 10.0.3.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source [my_public_ip] # 10.8.0 is VPN
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.1.0.0/16 -j SNAT --to-source [my_public_ip]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If don't have power type configured (i.e set to manual) check on the nodes installation tab. it might be stuck on "booting up" in that case restart the node you are bootstrapping to while conjuring-up.

we had similar issue and restarting the node seemed to fix it. hope this helps. good luck